# If $0<x<1$, show that $0<2x-2x^2<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $0<x<1$, show that $0<2x-2x^2<1$

I have so far:
$0<2x<2$ and $-2<-2x^2<0$

So, adding both inequalities, I get:
$-2<2x-2x^2<2$

Any hint on how to make the bounds tighter?

Comment: Can you argue instead that $x^2 < x$ for $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: I have applied the hint of @CameronWilliams:
$0<x^2<x$
$-x<x^2-x<0$

Answer (score 1):

You can take the inequality, split it by the two sides:
$$2x-2x^2>0$$
$$2x(1-x) > 0 \tag{1}$$
Divide both sides of $(1)$ by $2x$  since we know $0<x<1$:
$$1-x > 0$$
Rearranging:
$$\boxed{x<1}$$
Divide both sides of $(1)$  by $1-x$  since we know $0<x<1$ ,  then $1-x$ will be a positive:
$$2x > 0 $$
Dividing by 2:
$$\boxed{x>0}$$

---

This one could be solved by sketching:
$$-2x^2+2x-1<0\tag{2}$$
$$x\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$$$
$$\therefore \quad 0<x<1 $$

EDIT: Fixed typos and added full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$2x-2x^2=-2(x^2-x)=\frac12-2\left(x^2-x+\frac14\right)=\frac12-2\left(x-\frac12\right)^2.$$But\begin{align}x\in(0,1)&\implies\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\in\left[0,\frac14\right)\\&\implies-2\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\in\left(-\frac12,0\right]\\&\implies\frac12-2\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\in\left(0,\frac12\right].\end{align}

Comment: Did you mean $\left(0,\dfrac12\right]$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your bounds could be tighter, because $2x$ and $-2x^2$ aren't independent.

Complete the square:  $-2x^2+2x=-2x^2+2x-\frac12+\frac12=-2(x-\frac12)^2+\frac12\le\frac12$.

On the other hand, if $0<x<1$, then $x^2<x$, so $2x-2x^2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a change of variable helps:

Let $x=(1+u)/2$ with $-1\lt u\lt1$. Then

$$2x-2x^2=2x(1-x)=2\left(1+u\over2\right)\left(1-u\over2\right)={1-u^2\over2}$$

and we have $-1\lt u\lt1\implies 0\le u^2\lt1$, so that $0\lt(1-u^2)/2\le1/2\lt1$